# WSO2 IS SCIM can't access with oAuth token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want try access to REST SCIM with oAuth token, but i get error

{"Errors":[{"code":"500","description":"User is not authorized to perform provisioning"}]}

In docs says, what "WSO2 IS supports OAuth bearer token-based authentication for SCIM REST endpoints"

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS410/OAuth+Bearer+Token-
based+Authentication+for+SCIM+Endpoints

In version 5.3, has something changed?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Make sure you have provided `Authorization` header correctly like this.

```
curl -v -k -H "Authorization:Bearer b3fb1924-25e8-3ef9-9e55-6134bd778124" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

Comment: I get token as admin user.
 curl -v -k -H "Authorization: Bearer 2a16d0e0-3d7e-3649-aea9-4af43c6aa202" https://192.168.56.106:9443/wso2/scim/Users
> GET /wso2/scim/Users HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 192.168.56.106:9443
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer 2a16d0e0-3d7e-3649-aea9-4af43c6aa202
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
< 
* Closing connection 0
{"Errors":[{"code":"500","description":"User is not authorized to perform provisioning"}]}[root@wso2esb ~]#

Comment: Can you try instrospecting your token to make sure it was obtained by the admin user ?      curl -k -u admin:admin -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect

Comment: curl -k -u admin:admin -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'token=a21ebbcf-7551-319f-b6da-3595b09c05d3' https://192.168.56.106:9443/oauth2/introspect
{"active":true,"token_type":"Bearer","exp":1492499313,"iat":1492495713,"client_id":"dmPIahhgM6sp3Qa5DcviacH0dMsa","username":"admin@test.locl@carbon.super"}[